# How to map input values and .pfx certificate into base64 signature?

Tags: certificate, digital-signature

In api i have to send a request which contain inputdata which contains name,dob in list and also another parameter as a signature which contains base64 of input data and .pfx certificate.

I am excepting how to create signature using .pfx certificate and my input values also if possible how can i verify that my base64 is correct?